# Unity Addressables content update

Tags: unity-game-engine, assets, addressables

I am trying to update assets but download size after first launch always stay zero. On first launch download size get correct size. And after clear indexedDB showing correct. Platform is webgl. How can I check updated asset size?

```
private IEnumerator PreLoadData()
{
    AsyncOperationHandle<long> downloadSizeHandler = Addressables.GetDownloadSizeAsync(PreloadLabel);
    yield return downloadSizeHandler;

    OnSizeRecived.Invoke(downloadSizeHandler.Result);

    if (downloadSizeHandler.Result > 0)
    {
        AsyncOperationHandle downloadDependencies = Addressables.DownloadDependenciesAsync(PreloadLabel);

        while (!downloadDependencies.IsDone)
        {
            OnPercentChange.Invoke(downloadDependencies.PercentComplete);
            yield return null;
        }
    }

    OnDownloadCompleated.Invoke();
}
```

Comment: Did you try Simulate Groups mode?

Comment: it's the same in the editor